# Apple's "all or nothing" stance on iCloud: Is it a hard guideline?

Tags: ios, app-store-connect, icloud

The Apple documentation seems to consistently state that the user-generated documents should either **all** be stored locally or should **all** be stored on iCloud. Here is one example from [this iOS page](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/DataManagement/Conceptual/DocumentBasedAppPGiOS/ManageDocumentLifeCycle/ManageDocumentLifeCycle.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40011149-CH4-SW1) (the emphasis on *All* is theirs):

> *All* documents of an application are stored either in the local sandbox or in an iCloud container directory. A user should not be able to select individual documents for storage in iCloud.

I would like to allow users to manage documents individually: perhaps they want one to be local (to save space from their iCloud allowance), another to be on iCloud so they can manipulate it across devices, and another one to be on DropBox so they can copy it out into a friend's account or back it up manually or even edit it externally. The all-or-nothing approach would actually get in the way of flexibility, especially when I come to introduce [DropBox sync](https://www.dropbox.com/developers/sync). In my case, the individual choice also makes for simpler UI.

So the question is: Can I expect trouble at review time if I stick to my plans to allow users to choose their storage preference (local, iCloud and soon DropBox) per individual document? I haven't found specific guidelines for this. **Edit**: None of [the guidelines](https://developer.apple.com/app-store/review/guidelines/#functionality) even mention iCloud.

Comment: Although I don't have facts to support this opinion, I would expect trouble. Maybe not at the first review, but at some point, when you make a change or whatever, somebody will probably notice this and reject the app.

Comment: On what basis though? On the basis that they think all-or-nothing is more user-friendy? It seems a bit too subjective for rejecting an app.

Comment: Well, it's Apple - don't try to argue with them, it's pointless. And yes they think this is more user-friendly in terms of that users shouldn't spend time considering to put this in the cloud or not, if they could just put it in the cloud. Only if you have some docs in the cloud and some not, you can experience the bad situation that you are looking for a document in the cloud that hasn't been put there...

Comment: Thanks for your thoughts! I'm still not convinced, there are pros and cons to both approaches.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because [we're not Apple](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/255745/) and cannot answer this question.  No one except Apple can reliably tell you what to expect.

Answer (score 1):

It's a *should*, not a *must* (just as you *should* support all orientations on the iPad, but I don't think they'll force you to if the UI would need a complete rework). If you have a sufficiently compelling use-case and a non-clunky UI, I suspect they'll let it through, but I haven't tested this.

If it's not in the review guidelines, then I doubt it's ground for rejections apart from any requirement for "usability" — but honestly, given the average quality of UIs out there, I would not be too worried.

(Indeed, a strict interpretation of that guideline is that you're not supposed to use Dropbox/Google Drive/etc/roll-your-own-cloud-storage, but that's almost certainly not the intent unless they're inviting antitrust lawsuits.)

Answer (score 1):

I did a lot of testing for an app with iCloud. I started with the supposition that it would be transparent to the user whether everything was in iCloud or not, otherwise why would Apple suggest this approach?

Unfortunately, they did not test this fully before rolling it out. I had many problems in iCloud and UIDocument with iOS 4 then 5 (many radar entries of bizarre crashes). In fact, I probably spent half my development time working on this one issue rather than making the app better.

Anyway, the bottom line was that my app was MUCH slower when accessing docs running only on the cloud. Apple does try to cache docs in the Mobile Documents directories. There is minimal info on how to determine status of the caching and therefore try to work around unavailable docs or slowness. The UI ended up extremely jerky in the UITableViews or outright crashed in system libraries.

So, bottom line is my app stores everything locally. If a user makes a change, the app copies it up to iCloud itself and runs background processes to monitor the status of the doc getting up to the cloud. It also manually transfers files changed by another device on iCloud to keep everything in synch, again in background processes.

I've had no complaints at all from Apple reviewers. If I did, I would point them to the many radar entries.

Comment: I read a lot of similar posts, with the same expression of disappointment over spending so much time that could have been spent on improving other aspects of the app. Not very encouraging! Thanks and well done for finding a solution.